# What technical reasons prevent Canon's new hybrid AF working with non-STM lenses?

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus-motor, canon-650d

Canon's new Rebel T4i (a.k.a. EOS 650D) has a new "hybrid AF" mode, which allows continuous AF during video, but only when used with one of the new [STM lenses](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24109/what-does-stm-mean-on-a-canon-lens).

I've seen chatter on the web forums where it's suggested that this is a greedy move from Canon in order to force people into buying new lenses. I understand that STM allows a better AF experience during video, but is there a technical reason an STM motor is a *hard prerequisite*?

Comment: I don't know if you'd get a definitive answer, but I'd suggest it's a trade-off in customer complaints. Some people will whine about the lens restriction if they make it a hard requirement (call it the "typical greedy corporation" whine). Others will complain about the AF noise if they allow C-AF with all lenses (the "Canon is technically incompetent" whine). It's probably marginally better from a PR perspective to be seen as greedy by some than technically incompetent, even if the noise is a RTFM problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no hard prerequisite. You can use any lens you want. Just that STM "allows a better experience" as you say, because:

1. It is really silent. (no noise during video recording because of vibrations etc.)
2. Better design for Video (contrast-based) AF - smooth focus etc.

Also see the follwoing hands-on experience:

> We found the focus to be much snappier than on the T3i, in particular
>   it was very smooth with the new 18-135 STM lens attached to it. During
>   video, focus was nearly silent and smoothly moved to grab the subject
>   we wanted. **With a non-STM lens the focus isn’t as smooth, but it’s
>   still accurate, though the same trouble with low-contrast subjects
>   exists.**

Source [here](http://digitalcamerainfo.com/content/Canon-Rebel-T4i-First-Impressions-Review.htm#comment-553785992).

So for tl;dr readers: *it works also with non-STM lenses but if you can, use STM ones.*

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say anything official about hybrid AF working or not with non-STM lenses, but I have one clear experience with a third-party "Tamron SP 70-300 F/4-5.6 Di VC USD" lens, and this is awful:

In phase detect AF mode the lens needs 1-2 seconds to focus, in Live-View mode on the EOS 650D it takes 2-4 seconds, which is plainly slow. Especially above 200mm or with moving objects it has severe problems focusing **at all** in LiveView mode.
I often observe that the lens seeks its focus in the wrong direction first, focusing to the close end, then back to the far end when trying to re-focus on a distant landscape. It is my understanding that if it **would** use a hybrid AF then the camera should know at least sort of where the focus should be, instead of searching back and forth through the full range.

I therefore conclude in practice that either hybrid AF is not working with 3rd party lenses or that it is working too poor to even notice.